# Change listener without submitting the form

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I've got a list box and I want to catch change in selection in order to fill an other one according to it. I've tried in the following way:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="comunitaValle" value="#{struttura.nomeComunitaDiValle}" 
     onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{struttura.getComuniInComunita}">
<f:selectItems value="#{struttura.comunitaValleList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

It works fine, but the fact that in this page there are other parameters marked as

```
required="true"
```

and when the form is submitted I get my error messages controlling that those field has been set. How can I avoid to submit the entire form to avoid this to happen and still have the correct behaviour on the 2 list boxes?

EDIT:

I've reached a kind of solution (don't know if it is the best one) according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802483/2492962 :

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="comunitaValle" value="#{struttura.nomeComunitaDiValle}" 
      valueChangeListener="#{struttura.getComuniInComunita}" immediate="true">
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="cap"/>
<f:selectItems value="#{struttura.comunitaValleList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Can it be fine?
JBoss shows a warning message:

```
INFO  [lifecycle] WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
```

but the refresh seems fine.

Comment: Are you using JSF-2 or toolkit that provides AJAX-functionality? Since that sounds like the standard use-case for it.

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't able to do that with it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Correction to above: OP isn't using JSF 2.x at all.

Comment: Regarding your edit: are you trying to display FacesMessages in `getComuniInComunita`?

Comment: getComuniInComunita fill another drop down list according to the selected item in the first one. No FacesMessages are supposed to be shown here. I've got some FaceMessages in this page, indicating that some other fields hasn't been filled yet. Those are the "my error messages" I tried to explain in the first post and which I would not like to be shown after a selection of item in the drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reached a kind of solution (don't know if it is the best one) according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802483/2492962 :

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="comunitaValle" value="#{struttura.nomeComunitaDiValle}" 
      valueChangeListener="#{struttura.getComuniInComunita}" immediate="true">
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="cap"/>
<f:selectItems value="#{struttura.comunitaValleList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="cap" value="#{struttura.cap}"  >
<f:selectItems value="#{struttura.comuneIstatCapList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Finally found the canonical article on it: http://balusc.blogspot.de/2007/10/populate-child-menus.html - I'd say go ahead with your solution but please read the article for potential pitfalls.

Comment: Great! FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse(); is the answer I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Say your JSF looks like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="comunitaValle" value="#{struttura.nomeComunitaDiValle}">
   <f:ajax listener="#{struttura.getComuniInComunita}" 
           execute="@this" render="myListBox" />   
   <f:selectItems value="#{struttura.comunitaValleList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectManyListbox id="myListBox" value="#{struttura.backingValueList}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{struttura.listBoxValues}" var="val" 
                  itemLabel="#{val.name}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

Your backing bean then needs a method `getComuniInComunita` that accepts a `javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent` parameter (see the [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) for more information).

The `execute` attribute will cause JSF to only update/validate the select menu before invoking the `listener` method. Since your select menu only controls the list box(es), you can give a specific component id to update after the listener method finishes.

Comment: I'm getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent when calling public void getComuniInComunita(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)

Comment: @user2492962 um, *are* you using JSF-2? If not, which toolkit do you use to get ajax support?

Comment: uhm.. maybe not.. I've just found this jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1

Comment: FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion(); returns  1.2_12-b01-FCS, however it compiles correctly; the problem is runtime.

Comment: @user2492962 you probably have a JSF2 API jar on your compile time classpath, but are not deploying it to your app server.

Comment: Ok! I've asked to my boss and understood that we cannot use jsf2 due to some problems. Is there a way to do want I've asked using jsf1.x?

Comment: @andy JSF1 doesn't have built-in ajax functionality. You'd have to rely on your component library. Popular choices are Richfaces and PrimeFaces, do you run any of those?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Richfaces

Comment: @AnPe I'll post another answer when I get back, have a look at the `<a4j:ajax>` tag in the meantime.

Comment: `<a4j:ajax>` is from RichFaces 4 which is designed specifically for JSF 2.x. For JSF 1.x, there's RichFaces 3 which has `<a4j:support>`.

Comment: @BalusC yeah, I've been using RF4 for too long. `<a4j:support>` it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for JSF1.2, using [Richfaces3.3](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.4.Final/en/tlddoc/) `<a4j:support>`:

```
<a4j:region>
  <h:selectOneMenu id="comunitaValle" value="#{struttura.nomeComunitaDiValle}">
     <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{struttura.getComuniInComunita}" 
             ajaxSingle="true" reRender="myListBox" limitToList="true" />   
     <f:selectItems value="#{struttura.comunitaValleList}" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>

  <h:selectManyListbox id="myListBox" value="#{struttura.backingValueList}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{struttura.listBoxValues}" var="val" 
                    itemLabel="#{val.name}" />
  </h:selectManyListbox>
</a4j:region>
```

This is the closest I've come to replicating JSF-2. The `<a4j:region>` enables us to restrict processing to a subset of the page (works like the `execute` attribute in JSF-2).

In addition, you may find the Richfaces [architecture overview](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html) to be helpful.

Comment: Cannot find limitRender attribute for <a4j:support>.
Moreover this solution gives me an exception: org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodNotFoundException. Could it be a problem if getComuniInComunita return is void?

Comment: Sorry about that, `limitRender` is called `limitToList` in RF3, I've changed that in the answer. I'm not sure about the method not found exception. I was using Jboss EL with RF3, which hacked around limitations in previous EL versions. So it may well be that you need to conform to the exact signature in the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.4.Final/en/tlddoc/a4j/support.html), which requires a `Object` return value.

Comment: Still seems not to find my method. If there aren't errors, my own solution seems to fit better. Anything wrong with it?