# ValueChangeListener without submit

Tags: jsp

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{studentBean.studentName}" valueChangedListener="#{studentBean.valueChanged}" onchange="submit()">
   <f:selectItems value="#{studentBean.students}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In this code, there is onchange="submit()" statement. But I don't want to submit it right away. I want users to make their choice from selectOneMenu and menus will dynamically change according to users choice. So doing a submit is not an option for me.(Other parts of code to do it is not exist yet.)

And when I delete that submit valueChanged method does not fire.

I check this question :
[Change listener without submitting the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188203/change-listener-without-submitting-the-form)
But I don't want to add this:

```
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="cap"/>
```

Is there any other way?